# Joomla content next and prev content's images

Tags: php, navigation

How can I use PHP `echo` to get the next or prev page article title or image in current page?

I tried change some code in `article/default.php` like:

```
<div class="pull-<?php echo htmlspecialchars($imgfloat); ?> item-image"> <img
    <?php if ($images->image_fulltext_caption):
        echo 'class="caption"' . ' title="' . htmlspecialchars($images->image_fulltext_caption) . '"';
    endif; ?>
    src="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($images->image_fulltext); ?>" alt="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($images->image_fulltext_alt); ?>" itemprop="image"/> </div>
```

to

```
<div class="pull-<?php echo htmlspecialchars($imgfloat); ?> item-image"> <img
    <?php if ($images->image_fulltext_caption):
        echo 'class="caption"' . ' title="' . htmlspecialchars($images->image_fulltext_caption) . '"';
    endif; ?>
    src="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($next->images->image_fulltext); ?>" alt="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($images->image_fulltext_alt); ?>" itemprop="image"/> </div>
```

but it didn't work.

I don't want to change it in `pagenavigation.php`.

I'm using Joomla 3.4.

Answer (score 2):

You could override the page navigation by creating a template override file in `/templates/your_template/html/plg_content_pagenavigation/`. Copy the file `/plugins/content/pagenavigation/tmpl/default.php` to this place and edit as needed.
However since the plugin doesn't load the article pictures, you will not have the data available.

So the only solution is to replace the pagenavigation plugin with another one. I could imagine that there is such a plugin on JED, or you could create your own by copying the pagenavigation one and edit it.